# Xilinx sdk: linker won't link cross-c/c++

Tags: xilinx

I'm using the Xilinx SDK to compile for the Zynq 7020.

An example of the problem I'm having is this

SomeFile.c:

```
void someFunction () { }
```

SomeFile.h

```
void someFunction () ;
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
#include "SomeFile.h"
}

int main ( int , char const* * ) {
    someFunction () ; // This line
    return 0 ;
}
```

The line labeled "This line" gets a linker error because it cannot find the symbol "someFunction".

I know the `.c` file is being compiled (if I put a garbage character in it, it fails to build). I know it has the same prototype (but, with C linkage, that doesn't matter).

It seems the Xilinx suite isn't running the linker between C/C++ object files, and I don't know how to convince it to do so.

How do I fix this?

Note: this is using the gnu toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this is because the Xilinx SDK defaulted to compiling the `.c` file with g++, not gcc, which emitted the C++-mangled name for `someFunction` instead of the C name. Then, when the `.cpp` file used `extern "C"` to reference it, it was looking for a C-style symbol, not the C++-style [mangled] symbol.

I had to right click on the `.c` files to get to their build settings and manually change the compiler from `whatever-whatever-g++` to `whatever-whatever-gcc` then it worked.